# Are c++ standard library containers like std::queue guaranteed to be reentrant?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've seen people suggest that I should wrap standard containers such as std::queue and std::vector in a mutex lock or similar if i wish to use them.
I read that as needing a lock for each individual instance of a container being accessed by multiple threads, not per type or any utilization of the c++ standard library. But this assumes that the standard containers and standard library is guaranteed to be re-entrant.

Is there such a guarantee in the language?

Comment: No there isn't. That's it.

Comment: Reentrancy is only an issue for functions that can call themselves, and you'd have to work pretty hard to achieve that (e.g. use some kind of evil constructor).

Comment: The first time I read it I had thoughts similar to @KerrekSB.  Reading it a second time, I realized this was a better question than I had thought. You have correctly noted that reentrancy won't make objects thread safe, but without it, you could not use 2 different "independent" instances of the same class from different threads without concurrency control.

Comment: I don't have copies of the standards at hand to give a definitive answer, but have found this online: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2669.htm. I believe the answer will end up being that it was not guaranteed by the standard until C++ 11? or 14? but was the case in practice earlier. (Note that this would not apply to C library routines that are "inherited" by C++)

Comment: Yeah, in response to @KerrekSB, i don't think recursion is the only possible issue.

Imagine for example, if std::queue has a static integer that increments for each access. 

Further if this integer is global, and theoretically accessed by every single c++ library function, nothing is safe.

Comment: @Max: Yes, sure, but the main point is that reentrancy and thread-safety are orthogonal concepts. You can have non-reentrant, thread-safe functions, and re-entrant, thread-unsafe functions.

Comment: Yes, true. But it's kinda hard with the distinctions here, because the definition of thread-safety is that the class would handle multiple thread accessed internally. What i'm talking about is the measures necessary to wrap the standard lib to make it thread-safe. And to a degree, i worry that all bets are off unless i restrict myself to C features.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard says:

> Except where explicitly specified in this standard, it is implementation-defined which functions in the Standard C++ library may be recursively reentered.

Then it proceeds to specify that a function must be reentrant in, if I count them correctly, zero cases.

If one is to strictly follow the standard in this regard, the standard library suddenly becomes rather limited in its usefulness. A huge number of library functions call user-supplied functions. Writers of these functions, especially if those are themselves released as a library, in general don't know where they will be called from.

It is completely reasonable to assume that e.g. any constructor may be called from `emplace_back` of any standard container; if the user wishes to eliminate any uncertainty, he must refrain from any calls to `emplace_back` in any constructor. Any copy constructor is callable from e.g. `vector::resize` or `sort`, so one cannot manage vectors or do sorting in copy constructors. And so on, ad libitum.

This includes calling any third party component that might reasonably be using the standard library.

All these restrictions together probably mean that a large part of the standard library cannot be used in real world programs at all.

**Update**: this doesn't even start taking threads into consideration. With multiple threads, at least functions that deal with containers and algorithms must be reentrant. Imagine that `std::vector::operator[]` is not reentrant. This would mean that one cannot access two *different* vectors at the same time from two different threads! This is clearly not what the standard intends. I understand that this is your primary interest. To reiterate, no, I don't think there is reentrancy guarantee; and no, I don't think absence of such guarantee is reasonable in any way. --- end update.

My conclusion is that this is probably an oversight. The standard should mandate that all standard functions must be reentrant, unless otherwise specified.

I would

- completely ignore the possibility of of any standard function being non-reentrant, except when it is clear that the function cannot be reasonably made reentrant.
- raise an issue with the standards committee.

Comment: Is there a guarantee that, for example, the standard library doesn't contain a globally accessed integer, used in multiple standard function calls.

i.e. meaning, is there a guarantee that there is no memory access overlap?

Edit: I just realized, that this falls under the category of re-entrancy. My bad.

Comment: Reentrancy is on LWG's radar (see [LWG issue 2414](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/lwg-issues/2414)).

Comment: Thanks man, it clarifies you standpoint and states a suggested policy going forward which allows further debate.

Comment: @T.C. but they are trying to make it *worse!* (not significantly). They say you cannot call e.g. erase from resize of the same object.... ugh, I think I can live with that. Make it so that I can call resize from resize of a different object!

Comment: Don't read the (outdated) proposed wording, read the discussion :)

Comment: @T.C. Hmm, I don't see how this discussion proposes to solve anything. Unless by "function" one understand "all non-static member functions of the same object", and different objects have different functions, that is. Then one can at least touch different objects either recursively or from different threads. But what about non-member functions? Why no `sort` from within `sort`?

Comment: @T.C. No wait, they have seen the problem and moved it to "open", not all is lost.

Answer (score 3):

[Answer left for historical purposes, but see n.m.'s answer. There's no requirement on individual functions, but there *is* a single global non-requirement]

Yes, the standard guarantees reentrancy of member functions of standard containers.

Let me define what (non)-reentrancy means for functions. A reentrant function can be called with well-defined behavior on a thread while it is already on the call stack of that thread, i.e. executing. Obviously, this can only happen if the control flow temporarily left the reentrant function via a function call. If the behavior is not well-defined, the function is not reentrant.

(Leaf functions can't be said to be reentrant or non-reentrant, as the flow of control can only leave a leaf function by returning, but this isn't critical to the analysis).

Example:

```
int fac(int n) { return n==0 ? 1 : n * fac(n-1); }
```

The behavior of `fac(3)` is to return 6, even while `fac(4)` is running. Therefore, `fac` is reentrant.

The C++ Standard does define the behavior of member functions of standard containers. It also defines *all* restrictions under which such behavior is guaranteed. *None* of the member functions of standard containers have restrictions with respect to reentrancy. Therefore, any implementation which would restrict reentrancy is non-conformant.

Comment: Can you cite the sections of the spec you are referencing? "The C++ Standard does define the behavior of member functions of standard containers. It also defines all restrictions under which such behavior is guaranteed."

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: Cite all sections defining member functions? That's pretty much the second half of the standard, after the section which defines how the C++ library incorporates the C library. Or do you mean the relation between the Standard itself and implementations of that Standard, and what it means for an implementation to conform? Because that's the very first part of the Standard. (1.4 in particular). Most specifically but non-normative, see `17.5 [structure.elements]` and its footnote. This makes explicit what it means when no requirements are stated.

Comment: Maybe I'm reading your answer wrong, or maybe I'm reading the random copy of the standard I found incorrectly, but `17.5.5.8` sure seems to let reentrancy be implementation defined. "Except where explicitly specified in this standard, it is implementation-defined which functions in the C++ standard library may be recursively reentered." Edit: I also just saw your edit, so I will probably discontinue this thread :)